# Fabric.js - change color/fill/stroke of imported svg

Tags: jquery, fabricjs

Is there a way to change the color of an svg in fabric placed on the canvas using loadSVGFromURL?  The svg is just an arrow, if I can't set the fill or stroke, can I do this with a filter?

```
$("input:radio[id='arrow']").click(function() {
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('../scripts/svg/arrow.svg', function(objects) {
          var group = new fabric.PathGroup(objects, {
          left: 165,
          top: 100,
          width: 295,
          height: 40,
          fill: colourSet
        });
        canvas.add(group);
        canvas.renderAll();
          }); 
           });
```

Comment: http://fabricjs.com/hovering/ and http://fabricjs.com/customization/ will get you there

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var colorSet = '#00FFFF';

$("input:radio[id='arrow']").click(function() {
  fabric.loadSVGFromURL('../scripts/svg/arrow.svg', function(objects, options) {
    var shape = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    shape.set({
      left: 165,
      top: 100,
      width: 295,
      height: 40
    });
    if (shape.isSameColor && shape.isSameColor() || !shape.paths) {
      shape.setFill(colorSet);
    }
    else if (shape.paths) {
      for (var i = 0; i < shape.paths.length; i++) {
        shape.paths[i].setFill(colorSet);
      }
    }
    canvas.add(shape);
    canvas.renderAll();
  }); 
});
```

The function setFill on fabric.PathGroup objects only works if all paths has the same color:
https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/src/path_group.class.js#L99

Comment: Hey Kienz, thanks for your help with this but the arrow is not being added to the canvas at all with that code...

Comment: Hey Peter, i made jsfiddle example (with loadSVGFromString instead of loadSVGFromURL):
http://jsfiddle.net/Kienz/nFqpB/
Can you post your SVG?!

Comment: "You say color, I say colour, let's call the whole thing off..." (apologies to George and Ira Gershwin).  The problem was that I was using colourSet (English spelling) and the function referred to 'colorSet' (Yank spelling...).  All working now.

Comment: How i can change the color for canvas.setBackgroundImage() in my case its resizing the image from its actual size

Answer (score 0):

you can use OBJECT.setFill('FILL_COLOR');
for example

```
rect.setFill('red');
```

Comment: Is there an updated answer for 2021?